# Is it possible to move all NaN above diagonal in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

EDIT: Im editing question since original toy example was confusing, hope now it is more clear.

I'm trying to move all `NaN` value above diagonal to be able generate "pretty and clean" Seaborn heatmap from it (without grey spaces between the numbers).

Here is toy example:

```
import pandas as pd 
import seaborn as sns
import itertools

def get_pair_combinations(list_of_features):
    elements = list(itertools.combinations(list_of_features, 2))
    return elements

features = ['01_something', 'something_else', 'else', 'else232', 'foo'] 

elements = get_pair_combinations(list_of_features = features)

col1_list = []
col2_list = []
for element in elements:
    col1 = ''.join(element[0:1:])
    col2 = ''.join(element[1:2:])
    col1_list.append(col1)
    col2_list.append(col2)

val = [4, 21, 0, 16, 9, 2, 23, 1, 9, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(col1_list, col2_list, val)),
                      columns =['column_1', 'column_2', 'value'])
```

As a result of this code we getting dataframe. Next I'm using:

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='column_1', columns = 'column_2', values = 'value')
```

Results in:

```
column_2        else        else232      foo        something_else
column_1                
01_something    21.0        0.0          16.0       4.0
else            NaN         1.0          9.0        NaN
else232         NaN         NaN          10.0       NaN
something_else  9.0         2.0          23.0       NaN
```

My question is if it possible to move all NaN above/below diagonal to create less messy heat map from it?
We assuming that B,C is the same as C,B; (A,B = B,A) and so on

Example desire output:

```
column_2        something_else  else            else232         foo
column_1                
01_something    4.0             21.0            0.0             16.0
something_else  NaN             9.0             2.0             23.0
else            NaN             NaN             1.0             9.0
else232         NaN             NaN             NaN             10.0
```

I tried to clean heat map by using

```
mask = df_pivot.isnull()
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(df_pivot,annot = True,cmap=cmap, mask=mask)
```

Also I tried reorganising columns:

```
my_categories = list(set(col2_list))
df["column_2"] = df["column_2"].astype(pd.api.types.CategoricalDtype(categories= my_categories))
pt = pd.pivot_table(df, index='column_1', columns='column_2')
```

hoverer it still leaves grey spaces in the middle of heat map

Comment: Think of what algorithm you want e.g. swap rows or columns, then try to code this. If you run into problems, then post your question with what you've tried.

Comment: Your current output and your desired output do not match on e.g. (B, D) or (C, B)/(C, D). So it must be more then just "eliminating NaNs below the diagonal".

Comment: Thanks @Albert, my bad creating this example, in original code is fine

Comment: the toy example allows everything to fit perfectly, but what if there are extra values in the lower triangle? e.g. if a value also existed at row D, col C

Comment: also when i run your sample code, the pivot already gives the desired upper triangular output: `df_pivot = df.pivot(index='column_1', columns='column_2', values='value')`

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this? -

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def filter(index, col):
    values = df[[col]].apply(lambda x: sorted(x, key=pd.isnull))[col]
    if index == 0:
        return values
    values.iloc[index:] = np.NAN
    return values


result = {col: filter(index, col)
          for index, col in enumerate(df.columns.values)
          }

new_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

**Input -**

```
  column_2    B     C    D     E
0        A  4.0  21.0  0.0  16.0
1        B  NaN   NaN  NaN  23.0
2        C  NaN   9.0  1.0   9.0
3        D  2.0   NaN  NaN  10.0
```

**Output  -**

```
  column_2    B     C    D     E
0        A  4.0  21.0  0.0  16.0
1        B  NaN   9.0  1.0  23.0
2        C  NaN   NaN  NaN   9.0
3        D  NaN   NaN  NaN  10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code for generating data can be simplified a lot...  No "grey" is in heatmap and everything is above the diagonal

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import seaborn as sns

features = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] 
val = [4, 21, 0, 16, 9, 2, 23, 1, 9, 10]

df = pd.DataFrame(itertools.combinations(features, 2), columns=["column_1","column_2"]).assign(value=val)
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='column_1', columns = 'column_2', values = 'value')
sns_plot = sns.heatmap(df_pivot,annot = True,cmap="jet", mask=df_pivot.isna())
```

[image]

Comment: In fact you right, sorry for this I changes this example and now we not getting all number above diagonal